# Remove first character of each line of text using Java

Tags: java, regex

I need help to remove the first character (Z) of each line of text given below using Java. The number of lines can vary.

Input lines:

```
Z301052023KDE12   0000.062500000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000

Z301052023KDE11   0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
```

I am using below Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Rextester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        String inString = "Z301052023KDE12   0000.062500000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 \n" +
                          "Z301052023KDE11   0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000";

        inString = inString.replaceAll("^Z", "");
        System.out.println(inString);
    }
}
```

Actual output:

```
301052023KDE12   0000.062500000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 

Z301052023KDE11   0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
```

Expected output:

```
301052023KDE12   0000.062500000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 

301052023KDE11   0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
```

Comment: That is a single string `inString` variable. The`^Z` is applied only once as there is only one instance of `Z` at the start of the string.

Comment: @prasad_ since we used \n it will come as multiline.

Comment: It is still a single string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `^` match the beginning of every line instead of the entire string by enabling multi-line mode with the `(?m)` flag:

```
inString = inString.replaceAll("(?m)^Z", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`"^Z"`means that the string should start with letter `Z`. In the provided example, there is only one string that starts with `Z` and after that there are more characters. The next `Z` is preceded by a `\n`. A regex that could work in that case could be `(^Z|\nZ)`, which means that you want to capture an string that starts with `Z` or a `Z` that is preceded by a `\n`. Not sure if that could cover all the case that you have